# How to copy picture from Word to Powerpoint programmatically?

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint

I am creating a macro that converts a Word 2007 document into a structured PowerPoint 2007 presentation. I am looping over all the paragraphs of the document and copying them over to the new presentation.

I am able to copy and paste the paragraphs to the presentation just fine. But I also need to be able to copy and paste the pictures from the Word document into the PowerPoint (and in the right location between paragraphs).

So far, I am able to detect if a paragraph is a picture by looking at the paragraph's style attribute - it will say "Figure". But, I don't know what to do from there. After looking online, it looks like I should be able to do this:

```
paragraphFromDocument.Range.Copy
currentSlide.Shapes.Paste
```

But, this doesn't seem to work. How do I copy a picture from Word to PowerPoint?

Thanks

**EDIT**

---

I've also tried:

```
paragraphFromDocument.Range.CopyAsPicture
currentSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteMetafilePicture)
```

and get this error message:

> Shapes.PasteSpecial : Invalid Request. Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be posted here.

But, when I use that CopyAsPicture command, I am able to open up PowerPoint (with the picture still on the clipboard from the macro) and use the Paste Special command to paste the picture to the slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paragraphFromDocument.Range.Copy
currentSlide.Shapes.Paste
```

actually did end up working, but I had to remove all special characters from the range first. That is why it was giving me the error message.